# I have created a workflow with on `workflow_dispatch` in a pull request. How can I find and trigger it to test before merging?

Tags: github-actions

I have created a workflow with on `workflow_dispatch` in a pull request.
Let's say: `sample.yml`

Its a manual workflow with lots of inputs before it starts to run. Now since its within a pull request, I can't view it in actions tab of github. I need to do extensive testing before I could merge it to master. Does anyone know the right procedure to detect and run this workflow which is just part of a branch and only in pull request and not yet in master?

Or I have to always create it in master and test there itself?

Comment: You won't be able to test it through the UI without committing the workflow on the repository _default_ branch. However, you will be able to trigger it by using the [gh workflow run](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run) command with the GitHub CLI.

Comment: Note that you can also use [nektos/act](https://github.com/nektos/act) to test your workflow locally.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I've never been able to run workflows (even with `gh run workflow`) unless they've been merged to the main branch. Has this worked for you before?

Comment: Even using the `-r, --ref <string>` command flag @EightyEight? I don't remember having any trouble with this.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the question is but this is how you will create a workflow that triggers on a pull request where you can specify the branch name. The "branch_name" can be any branch you want

```
name: Workflow name
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "branch_name" ]

jobs:
    ...
```

Also a side note: you cannot have a workflow that both has inputs and triggers on a pull request. If it has inputs something needs to be passing those inputs (such as another workflow, REST API call or a manual trigger)